# Can Canon T70 be converted to digital?

Tags: lens, canon, dslr

Is it possible to convert my Canon T70 to digital format? Will I still be able to use my collection of lenses after conversion?

Answer (score 5):

**Theoretically Possible? Yes.**

Back in 2001 there was a [company](http://cultureandcommunication.org/deadmedia/index.php/Silicon_Film) that introduced an idea too far ahead of its time: to create digital modules that would fit inside conventional 35mm film cameras. But the technology to do it in such a small package was not available and it never got into production.

[image: e-film EFS-1]

**Doable from a practical standpoint? Not unless you have resources similar to what was available to Kodak Laboratories in the 1980s and 1990s.**

Some of the earliest digital cameras not tied down to a stationary lab, personal computer, or installed in a NASA space probe were built around the bodies of then-current film cameras. In 1991, Kodak released the first professional digital camera system (DCS) aimed at photojournalists. It was a Nikon F-3 film camera equipped by Kodak with a 1.3 megapixel sensor. It required a constant wired connection to a hard disk system used to store the image data.

[image: Nikon DCS]

1995 saw the debut of Canon's first Digital EOS cameras the EOS DCS 3 and EOS DCS 5. With a 1.3 Megapixel CCD sensor and a price tag of 12,000 euro the [EOS DCS 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_DCS_3), based on a modified EOS 1N film camera attached to a Kodak NC2000e digital camera back, gave photographic agencies the ability to produce transmission-ready images straight out of the camera. A digital module small enough to be attached directly to the base of the camera allowed it to be free of any umbilical cords connecting it to a separate unit.

[image: EOS DCS 3]

Fully compatible with the entire range of EF lenses, the EOS DCS 3 was developed in collaboration with Kodak who produced the major electronic components.

Your Canon T70 is a pre-EOS era film camera that uses the FD lens mount system and no commercially available digital cameras have ever been produced by Canon or Kodak for that mount. Likewise, no digital backs and accompanying modules, such as were made for the Nikon F-3 and Canon EOS 1N film cameras, have ever been developed for an FD mount camera. So if you convert your T70 to digital you would need to build the digital parts yourself, just as Canon and Kodak did for the EOS 1N back in the 1990s.

Answer (score 2):

If your priority is on continuing to use FD mount lenses, your best option is to get a mirrorless camera with an FD adapter.  The Sony E-mount system is a great choice for this, since it offers both APS-C (eg, A6000) and full-frame cameras (eg, A7) in the same system, with a common lens mount.

There is a mirrorless system by Canon too, but it <s>is</s> was, at the time this answer was written, a niche compared to the Fujifilm and Sony systems.

"Full Frame" will mean your lenses will keep their effective focal length.  "APS-C" will add a multiplier of 1.5x to your effective focal lengths (so 35mm will be a normal, 50mm a short portrait lens...) - with the potential advantage of only using the middle part of the image, where most (not all) lenses are at their best performance.

If some of your collected lenses are second-grade (eg, not made by Canon or one of the better third-party makers), you might find their performance no longer satisfactory on a digital setup.

Comment: The "niche" Canon mirrorless was the EOS-M?  Perhaps worthwhile to update for Canon and Nikon full-frame options?

Comment: Thanks for the help with the strikethrough! Only mentioned Canon because there is Canon in the original question... and I would doubt many would consider a Nikon mirrorless a first choice if wanting to work with adapted lenses...

Comment: Agree. They aren't among my first choices. Suggested mentioning them for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't put a digital back on the T70.  It is not available.  I suggest a mirrorless camera with an FD glassless adapter if you must use your FD lenses. You may find the 2x crop factor unreasonable, though.

Or shoot film and get an Epson scanner.

Comment: He could perfectly well get a basic full frame mirrorless, like a first gen A7.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to convert my Canon T 70 to digital format

**No.** The digital sensor and accompanying electronics in a digital SLR are integral to the body, not something that can be added on after the fact.

> will I still be able to use my collection of lenses

Since you can't convert your camera, you'd need to replace it with a digital body. However, Canon changed its lens mount in 1987, so any new body you buy will require EF mount lenses. Although there are FD to EF converters that will let you attach your old FD lenses to an EF body, those old lenses will still be manual focus, manual aperture lenses. Replacing them with EF lenses is the recommended path.

Comment: You've never attached a digital back to an old MF film camera or seen it done, have you?

Comment: @MichaelClark I was going to mention digital backs, but didn't want to complicate an otherwise clear-cut issue. Yes, I'm aware of digital backs for medium format cameras, but I'm not aware of any digital backs available for 35mm film SLRs. Even though the earliest DSLRs from Kodak were built around film bodies, you couldn't swap backs to change between film and digital. And certainly there's no digital back for the T70.

Comment: You said, "The digital sensor and accompanying electronics in a digital camera are integral to the body, not something that can be added on after the fact." A digital back is exactly what you describe as "... not something that can be added on after the fact."

Comment: OK. Changed *digital camera* to *DSLR* to avoid any possibility of confusion. But MF is a pretty different beast, as the back encapsulates the entire film transport mechanism which is integral to the body of an SLR.

Comment: The DSC cameras produced by Kodak were essentially digital backs semi-permanently attached to off-the-shelf film cameras. If you notice, the shutter control on the Nikon is on an add-on grip similar to the motor drive grips of the time and not modified into the mechanical shutter button of the film camera. Since the EOS film cameras were already totally electronically controlled there was no need to do this for the Canon version. The T 70 was revolutionary in that it was the first electronically controlled Canon SLR and in many ways was the prototypical EOS camera but built for the FD mount.

Comment: @Michael It is stretching the truth to say "off-the-shelf". IMO, the OP is talking about a manufacturer-sanctioned, straightforward, do-it-yourself, quick-fix, turn-your-film-camera-into-a-digital-camera solution. You are complicating the issue.

Comment: The OP asked if it is possible. Yes, it is possible. And no, it doesn't make any sense. A good answer should convey both parts.

Comment: As I read the question, the OP seems to be asking for a practical answer, not a theoretical one. This "well, it's *possible* if you have the capability to engineer and fabricate a digital back" idea may be well intentioned, but I don't think it's constructive or useful or necessary in a good answer to this question.

Comment: Don't interpret the question. Answers are for all readers, not just for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In theory,that is quite possible.We didn't think that digital cameras can develop and now replace film cameras just in few decades.And in future,no one can be sure that analog cameras won't comeback.Since we have already built the flexible OLED(organic light emitting diode) display,we can build an flexible sensor for fitting in any vintage cameras as well.