# modding analog camera to digital

Tags: camera

This may be a dumb question for experts but i still want to ask as I don't want to throw away my old analog canon eos300. Has anyone attempted modding it from analog camera digital by adding CCD and electronics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad. This is likely to generate a _lot_ of discussion about the issues involved, design ideas, pitfalls & gotchas, etc. Stack Exchange sites are not suited to such a high level of discussion that this will likely generate.

Comment: This might be something better discussed on [Hackaday](http://hackaday.io).

Comment: see also: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/84824/38159

Answer (score -2):

Check out re35 website a retrofit 35mm cassette that sports a digital imaging sensor.

Comment: Unfortunately, that site looks real but there is no actual product. It is a "design concept". See the disclaimer at the bottom of the page.